# In playframework 2.0, how do I use the session object in templates?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

In playframework 1.x, session is just an implicit object in templates but it seems like it is gone in playframework 2.0. 
Is there a way for me to use the session object in the templates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember right, you should be able to get a value stored in session like this:

```
@session.get("mySessionVar")
```

Comment: Seems to work only from Java controller out of the box. If you are in scala world, you have to specify a (implict) parameter called session like this: @()(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session) Unfortunatelly you have to specify this in all of you templates( eg. actionTemplate->main->header).